# SQL Query getting the latest record of the Group and calculate the value of those particular records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do have the following table (just a sample) and would like to get the Points subtract from Record2 to Record1. (Record2-Record1) from the latest record of both record1 and 2. The records are entered in category of Match. 1 Match will consists of 2 records which are Record 1 and Record 2.
The output will be 3 as the newest record is ID 3 and 4 from the Match2.)

| ID | Name | Points | TimeRecorded | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Record 1 | 3 | 2-Mar 2pm | 1 |
| 2 | Record 2 | 5 | 2-Mar 2pm | 1 |
| 3 | Record 1 | 5 | 4-Mar 5pm | 2 |
| 4 | Record 2 | 8 | 4-Mar 5pm | 2 |

I tried to get the value of subtracting both query as below. But I feel that this is not the good way as it is hard coded for the match and the Name of the record. May I know how to construct a better query in order to get the latest record of the grouped match and calculate the points whereby subtracting Record1 from Record2.

```
SELECT
    (select Points from RunRecord where Name= 'Record2' AND Match = 2)
  - (select Points  from RunRecord where  Name= 'Record1' AND Match = 2)
```

Comment: What is the type of the `TimeRecorded` column?  Is it text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is in timestamp (DateTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY TimeRecorded DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Record 2' THEN Points END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'Record 1' THEN Points END) AS diff
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The CTE assigns a row number for each group of records of the same name, with 1 being assigned to the most recent record.  Then, we aggregate over the entire table and pivot out the points to find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rank()` window function to rank the records by `match` descending. Then take the top of the ranked records and use conditional aggregation to control the sign of the `points` added.

```
SELECT sum(CASE x.name
             WHEN 'Record2' THEN
               x.points
             WHEN 'Record1' THEN
               -x.points
           END)
       FROM (SELECT rr.name,
                    rr.points,
                    rank() OVER (ORDER BY rr.match DESC) r
                    FROM runrecord rr
                    WHERE name IN ('Record1',
                                   'Record2')) x
       WHERE x.r = 1;
```